# How to add directions with a link to a webform in Drupal 7

Tags: webforms

I'm creating forms with the webform module. I'd like to add 'directions for filling out the form at the top of the form. I'd like those directions to include a link to another form if users clicked the wrong form.

This seems like it should be simple to do, but I can't figure out how to do it. When I add the directions with the link in a  and put that at the top I get the link but no paragraphs, just one long running line of text, no matter how I split it up in the editor window. If I use a  field, not only does it look ugly (even when disabled), because it has a white background on a gray background site, but it displays the link as html code etc..

I have wysiwyg enabled on my site and it shows up in other places but not on these editor windows so I can't use that (or select filtered html/full as those options also aren't available) in those data types I tried.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a custom module and using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) as shown in this [example](https://www.drupal.org/node/1702628).

You can add a form element of type [#markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute) to add custom html in your form. And set the [#weight](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval) to a low number, `-50` for instance, for your markup element to show at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have editor limitations on that content type. Other than that make sure you are adding your directions to the 'body' field.

When editing the webform go to the 'edit' tab adjacent (where you set the title) the body field should have a switch. If that was not present, you need to check your editor module settings. Sometimes called profiles depends which one you use.

I recall one of them required that each content type had to be picked in the editor settings.